# How to get an item in SQL if it matches a conditional based on many rows?

Tags: sql

I am trying to return all distinct `name`s where they have a `grade` of `A` AND they do NOT have a grade of `F`. In this case, the SQL statement would just return `userA`.

How can I return the user when I need a conditional that relies on multiple rows?

| Name | Grade |
| --- | --- |
| userA | A |
| userA | B |
| userA | C |
| userB | A |
| userB | B |
| userB | F |
| userC | B |
| userC | C |
| userC | D |

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To obtain a unique list of names:

```
GROUP BY name
```

To restrict the result to names with at least one grade of 'A'

```
HAVING SUM(grade = 'A') > 0
```

and also with no grade of 'F'

```
   AND SUM(grade = 'F') = 0
```

The final SQL for MySQL ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=04d909219dd9b92d99856e2ca8cb3350)):

```
SELECT name
  FROM grades
 GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(grade = 'A') > 0
   AND SUM(grade = 'F') = 0
;
```

and as Akina mentions, because MySQL treats 0 as false and non-0 as true, this is equivalent to:

```
SELECT name
  FROM grades
 GROUP BY name
HAVING     SUM(grade = 'A')
   AND NOT SUM(grade = 'F')
;
```

For PG, a similar approach is ([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5eee980eb729a84f9cc1ab9b410566cd)), which is also fine for MySQL:

```
SELECT name
  FROM grades
 GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN grade = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
;
```

or for just PG:

```
SELECT name
  FROM grades
 GROUP BY name
HAVING SUM((grade = 'A')::int) > 0
   AND SUM((grade = 'F')::int) = 0
;
```

Comment: In MySQL you may use even `HAVING SUM(grade = 'A') AND NOT SUM(grade = 'F')`.